# Charging and using Otg simultaneously with hub on Android 11

Tags: charging, usb-on-the-go

does anyone who has a powkiddy x18s (Android 11) know if it is possible to use a hub with a PD that charges the device and can use a mouse at the same time (simultaneously)?

because I connected a usb 3.0 hub with pd (charging) and it cannot use the 2 outputs (pd and usb) simultaneously.

Either it charges, or it uses the USB output (in my case a connected mouse)

Does anyone know the reason? I have a Redmi Note 8 Pro (Android 10) and it can work correctly with this PD+USB hub, whereas the X18s with Android 11 does not work with both outputs simultaneously.

I enabled developer mode on Android and turned on USB debugging mode, and it didn't work. I also changed the USB default mode to "file transfer" and it didn't solve the problem.

Has anyone managed to solve this yet?

Comment: My guess is that the Redmi Note 8 Pro supports charging via USB PD, where as the powkiddy x18s only supports regular charging (no USB PD support).